# Validate radio button and select dropdown list with Materialize framework

Tags: jquery, materialize

--Update: Thanks to pandamakes I have a solution for the select dropdown.  Still looking for solution for radio button.  Thank you in advance --

So I'm trying to make a radio button and select required. When not including the Materialize js it works fine as seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/foch6otj/1/

Unfortunately, this seems incompatible with Materialize and the validation alerts stop showing, in fact the select disappeared completely. However, I found a work around to both display the select and the alert, which is the $("select").material_select() section of code, however, the alert isn't positioned correctly.  For some reason it doesn't show up in this code snippet but on my local MAMP server it appears as in this image:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9dUy.png)

I would like to keep the materialize styling if possible, I realise I can use other methods to validate the field but as the 10+ other fields on my form validate well and I like the materialize style, I'd love to have this work the same way. If anyone knows how to solve either of these two problems I'd really appreciate it.  Also like to say thanks to all those who answer questions on this site, you've been really helpful helping me build a site for the first time in 10+ years.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").material_select();

    $("select[required]").css({position: "absolute", display: "inline", height: 0, padding: 0, width: 0});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <body>
  <div class="row">
     <form name="form1" id="form1" class="col s12" method="post" action="insert2.php">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <select class="validate" name="NameTitle" required="required">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
       <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
       <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
       <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
       <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
     </select>
    <label for="NameTitle">Title:</label>
    </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
     <label class="active" for="ZoneOverseasCarer">Zone / Overseas / Carer:</label>
    <div>
        <div class="input-field col s3">
         <input name="ZoneOverseasCarer" class="with-gap" type="radio" id="ZoneOverseasCarerNo" value="No" required/>
         <label for="ZoneOverseasCarerNo">No</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s3">
           <input name="ZoneOverseasCarer" class="with-gap" type="radio" id="ZoneOverseasCarerYes" value="Yes"/>
           <label for="ZoneOverseasCarerYes">Yes</label>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>    
   <div class="input-field col s12">
       <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
     </div>
  </form>
  </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems materializecss not rendering select validation box is a known issue ([link](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1390)).

This is not a perfect solution, but it's quick and dirty.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#NameTitle').material_select()

    $("select[required]").css({
    display: "block", 
    'margin-top':'-15px',
    height: 0, 
    padding: 0, 
    width: 0});
})
```

working jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xgui3783/6qjz1czm/)

Comment: Thank you, that is a better solution than I had for the select section.  Would you happen to have an option for correcting the radio buttons?